# Is it possible to change a pinned icon in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I have a couple of command prompts that start with different environment variables and a couple of applications with the generic "Application Icon", is there any way to give them different icons?  .

Also is there anyway to pin a shortcut to the taskbar?

**Edit**: I figured out why I was having problems now.  If you already have a shortcut pinned to the taskbar that points to one application, you cannot pin another shortcut to the application that points to the same application (it shows an x when you drag it to the taskbar).  This is why I was having problems, as I already had the same application on the taskbar and I wanted to pin a different version with different startup commands.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to change a pinned icon in windows 7?"

To change a shortcuts icon that is pinned to the taskbar can be done indirectly... The easiest method I've found is to drag it to desktop, unpin it, modify it, re-pin it.

> I have a couple of command prompts that start with different environment variables and a couple of applications with the generic "Application Icon", is there any way to give them different icons?

If you have a shortcut for each of the command prompts each of them can have there own individual icon.  Right Click properties, change icon, select an ico or exe file, or create an ico and hunt down it.

> Also is there anyway to pin a shortcut to the taskbar?

Right Click > Pin to Taskbar (from startup menu) otherwise just drag it there.

Try Ctrl + Shift + RightClick to get to properties but visual changes to the icon are not updated even after reboot.  I  guess that it is cached somewhere.  I'll let someone more knowledgeable jump in and that facet answer.

Sorry, I fumbled the answer at first. Have I answered your questions; or would you like me to expand or rephrase anything.

Comment: For me. the icon is changed as long as the program is closed. When opened, real program icon shows. Any one is able to override this?

Answer (score 1):

How about making a batch file for each? Then Windows won't know what the batch file is and won't keep you from having the two icons pinned at the same time. For example comspec1.cmd and comspec2.cmd.

Answer (score 0):

no, you have to unpin it, make a shortcut on the desktop or something, change the icon then re-pin it.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your edit:
You could try making a shortcut to a shortcut.

Maybe make a shortcut in the app folder with your CLI arguments and make a shortcut to that?