# Change icon of file

Tags: windows-7, python, taskbar, icons

For those of you into Python you probably know about IDLE.  I use it so often that I have it pinned to my taskbar, but I've got a metro/Modern UI theme going so I want to change the icon of it.  The problem is that because IDLE is a python file, you can't change the icon like I normally do using [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/36024/is-it-possible-to-change-a-pinned-icon-in-windows-7), because it's a file rather than an application.  So when you go to pin it, it just pins the normal python file icon with IDLE pinned as a file!  I then tried changing the default icon associated with .py files and found that it didn't work; the default python icon still stayed there (see below image)!  What I'm trying to do is change the icon to a different one; is there a way to do this other than the methods I've already tried?

[image: Default Python pinned icon]
The default python icon

[image: Attempting to pin IDLE result in this]
Attempting to pin IDLE results in this

[image: problematic new icon appearing]

Comment: You can also compile python script to .exe or make launcher .exe on other language who will pass command line to python.

Comment: @crazypotato I should have thought of that!  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll let you know if it doesn't work

Comment: Does anything at http://www.maxi-pedia.com/change+icon+greyed+out help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Create a shortcut on the desktop](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-create-shortcuts) (right click on desktop->new->shortcut) then enter `"cmd"` in the place of type the location of the item.
2. [Change icon](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/53402-shortcut-change-icon.html) and name on "cmd" shortcut for what you need.(DONT change path)
3. Drag this shortcut to the taskbar so its will be pinned.
4. Press Win+R, paste and run this:
   `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`
5. Find what you pinned in the open directory and change path in
   "cmd" shortcut for what you need.

Path alone for easy copy:

%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar

[IDLE path so you can set it in shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118260/how-to-start-idle-python-editor-without-using-the-shortcut-on-windows-vista)

---

Another way:

I will show how make launcher .exe with custom icon on [Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com).

After install [Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) and [Editor](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/). Right click on desktop->New->Autoit Script. Right click on this created file->Edit. Now you should see ScITE window after line "Add your code below here" add this code:

```
$executable="C:\App\pythonw.exe"
$parameter="C:\App\IDLE.py"
$workingdir="C:\App\"
run('"'&$executable&'" "'&$parameter&'"',$workingdir)
```

- change path $executable in quotes for pythonw.exe
- change path $parameter in quotes for IDLE script
- change path $workingdir in quotes for working directory
  pythonw.exe(in most cases same directory where locate pythonw.exe)

in the ScITE window press Tools->Compile->Change icon->Compile script.
In same directory where autoit script was created now .exe with custom icon who can run for example IDLE.

But i dont think this solve problem with appearing icon on taskbar with metro theme.

Comment: Thanks for that, but the 'change icon' option is greyed out when I do that!  Still, I appreciate the effort!

Comment: Almost everything what i answer i test before post. So how possible "Change icon" greyed option on newly created "cmd" shortcut on desktop? Show screenshot. Probably my english too bad so you cant understand.

Comment: I don't know I'm afraid.  You suggest a method very similar to what I originally did (although I didn't do steps 4 and 5 originally, but when I did it, it still didn't work - see edit).  I just don't know how it can be changed without making it an application!

Comment: You dont follow my instructions:( You should create shortcut "cmd" not python thing. The only thing you can change its when i write **for what you need.**

Comment: Ah, I see I misread it.  Thanks for that.  I was making the shortcut to the desktop then changing the path instead of changing the path later on!  My apologies.  It works well, the only thing is that it opens a new icon on the taskbar (i.e. next to the pinned IDLE shortcut there is another icon).  Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Not sure if i understand correctly. You should unpin IDLE in the taskbar and change path of the newly created shortcut(this shortcut locate now at %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar) to IDLE path. In my post here link about how you can find IDLE path.

Comment: Yes, I've done that and it's working i.e. when I click on the shortcut it opens IDLE and I've changed the icon to what I want, so that works.  The problem I've got now is that when I click the shortcut on the taskbar another icon on the taskbar appears (I'll post a screenshot in a minute)

Comment: I cant reproduce this. Think its something with  metro/Modern UI theme. Is this theme make Windows 7 looks like Windows 8? Who will need this xD Can you disable theme for test? If with disabled theme works normally i cant help you. You should then use compiled IDLE or launcher. Or even another IDE i use [pyscripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/)

Comment: Yeah, it's a windows 9 skinpack (better than the win 8 one I think). I'll just compile it and that should work fine.  Thanks for all your help!